# What's the difference between knex.raw() and knex.schema.raw()?

Tags: knex.js

`knex.raw(sql, bindings)` and `knex.schema.raw(statement)`.

It seems that these two functions have different signature.

If they are equivalent, how can I use `knex.schema.raw(statement)` and pass `bindings` to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`knex.raw` creates query builder instance which can be executed right away.

With `knex.schema.*` things work a bit different manner. Knex schema methods creates an array of queries, which are then executed one by one when schema builder is resolved.

So for example if you do `knex.schema.createTable(t => ...).raw('DROP ALL').toSQL()` you will see that there are multiple queries generated and they all will be executed when schema builder is triggered.

If you do just `await knex.schema.raw('SELECT 1')` or `await knex.raw('SELECT 1')`, there won't be any differences. But with `knex.schema.raw` you can also do:

```
await knex.schema.raw('SELECT 1').raw('SELECT 2');
```

Which returns an array where results of both of the queries are found. So it is totally possible to exploit that feature also for running multiple queries one after another like this:

```
await knex.schema
  .raw('?', [knex('table1').where('id', 1)])
  .raw('?', [knex('table2').where('id', 2)]);
```

Also `knex.schema.raw` doesn't return `QueryBuilder`, but it returns `SchemaBuilder` with different methods available.

So `knex.schema.raw` cannot be used as a part of normal queries for example in `knex('table').where(knex.raw('id = 1'))`

Comment: Your example does not work. The function signature is: `knex.schema.raw(statement: string): SchemaBuilder;` It doesn't support placement and pass bindings.

Comment: @slideshowp2 I'm sorry to prove you wrong https://runkit.com/embed/7spjw0es75y9 It works just fine. I suppose TypeScript typings are just missing that API like many other.